# Why is POP slow when using register R12?

Tags: performance, x86, intel, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

On recent Intel CPUs, the `POP` instruction usually has a throughput of 2 instructions per cycle. However, when using register `R12` (or `RSP`, which has the same encoding except for the prefix), the throughput drops to 1 per cycle if the instructions go through the legacy decoders (the throughput stays at around 2 per cycle if the µops come from the DSB).

This can be reproduced using [nanoBench](https://github.com/andreas-abel/nanoBench) as follows:

```
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12"
```

Further experiments on a Haswell machine show the following: When adding between 1 and 4 `nops`,

```
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12; nop;"
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12; nop; nop;"
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12; nop; nop; nop;"
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12; nop; nop; nop; nop;"
```

the execution time increases to 2 cycles. When adding a 5th `nop`,

```
sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm "pop R12; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop;"
```

the execution time increases to 3 cycles. This suggests that no other instruction can be decoded in the same cycle as a `pop R12` instruction. (When using a different register, e.g., `R11`, the last example needs 1.5 cycles.)

On Skylake, the execution time stays at 1 cycle when adding between 1 and 3 `nops`, and increases to 2 for between 4 and 7 `nops`. This suggests that `pop R12` is an instruction that requires the complex decoder, even though it has just one µop (see also [Can the simple decoders in recent Intel microarchitectures handle all 1-µop instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980149/can-the-simple-decoders-in-recent-intel-microarchitectures-handle-all-1-%C2%B5op-inst))

Why is the `POP` instruction decoded differently when using register `R12`? Are there any other instructions for which this is also the case?

Comment: `r12` has the same encoding as `rsp` except for the bit in the `REX` prefix, perhaps that "scares" the decoder?

Comment: @harold: That would make sense; the short form of `pop reg` encodes the register as part of the "opcode" byte, and presumably the primary filtering of which decoder can decode which instruction is by the opcode byte (not accounting for prefixes).  I wonder if we'd see the same effect with the 2-byte ModRM encoding of `pop r/m64` that encodes RSP or R12 via the ModRM byte.  `pop rsp` is special because it's just `mov rsp, [old_rsp]` (or as the manual puts it, writing R/ESP *after* applying the increment, but still loading from the old top-of-stack.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop).

Comment: Does either encoding of `pop r12` (or `pop rsp`) trigger a stack-sync uop?  On Intel, we'd normally expect only 1 stack sync uop per however many `pop r12` it takes the stack engine's offset to overflow.

Comment: @PeterCordes With the 2-byte ModRM encoding of `pop R12`, the effect does not occur.

Comment: Perhaps worth submitting patches for GAS and NASM to optimize for speed instead of size with this instruction, then.  Or for GCC to avoid R12 when possible, to avoid pop r12 in the epilogue.  Or line it up 4 insns before ret, so you can get a full decode-group before the multi-uop `ret` hits the decoders.

Comment: @PeterCordes On Haswell, there is one stack-sync uop for every ~25 `pop R12`; there are no additional stack-sync uops. For `pop RSP`, there are no stack-sync uops; however, `pop RSP` decodes to 3 uops, whereas `pop R12` decodes to just 1 uop (for both encodings).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Workaround: the `pop r/m64` encoding of `pop r12` doesn't have this decode penalty**.  (Thanks @Andreas for testing my guess.)

```
db  0x41, 0x8f, 0xc4        ; REX.B=1  8F /0  pop r/m64  = pop r12
```

---

The standard encoding of **`pop r12` has the same opcode byte as `pop rsp`, differing only by a REX**.  (The [short form encoding](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop) puts the register number in the low 3 bits of that 1 byte).

`pop rsp` is special cased even in the decoders; on Haswell it's 3 uops<sup>1</sup> so clearly only the complex decoder can decode it.  `pop r12` also getting penalized makes sense if **the primary filtering of which decoder can decode which instruction is by the opcode byte (not accounting for prefixes)**, at least for *this* group of opcodes.  Whether this really reflects the exact internals, it's at least a useful mental model to understand why pop modrm doesn't have this effect.  (Although normally you'd only use `pop r/m64` with a memory destination, which would mean multi-uop and thus complex-decoder only.)  See *[Can the simple decoders in recent Intel microarchitectures handle all 1-µop instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980149/can-the-simple-decoders-in-recent-intel-microarchitectures-handle-all-1-%C2%B5op-inst)* for more about this effect for other opcodes.

`push rsp` is 2 total uops on Haswell, unlike most `push reg` instructions being 1 uop.  But likely that extra uop is just a stack-sync inserted during issue/rename (because of reading RSP), *not* during decode.  @Andreas reports that `push rsp` and `push r12` both show no special effects in the decoder (and I assume uop cache). Just 1 micro-fused uop, with/without a stack-sync uop when it executes.

Opcodes like `FF /0 inc r/m32` where the same leading byte is shared between different instructions (overloading the modrm `/r` field as extra opcode bytes) might be interesting to check on, if there are some single-uop instructions that share a leading byte with multi-uop instructions.  Like maybe `C0 /4` SHL r/m8,imm8 vs. `C0 /2` RCL r/m8, imm8.  http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html.  But SHL with a memory destination can already be multiple uops, so it might get optimistically attempted by the simple decoders anyway, and succeed if it turns out to be single-uop?  While perhaps `pop r12` bails out early in the simple decoders instead of detecting the REX prefix.

It would make sense for Intel to spend the transistors to make sure common instructions like immediate shifts can decode efficiently, moreso than for less-common instructions like `pop r12` which you'll normally only find in function epilogues, and thus usually not in inner loop.  Only larger loops that include function calls.

---

**Footnote 1**: `pop rsp` is special because it's just `mov rsp, [rsp]`. (Or as the manual puts it, *The POP ESP instruction increments the stack pointer (ESP) before data at the old top of stack is written into the destination.*  Haswell's 3-uop implementation seems unnecessary vs. literally the same 1 uop as `mov rsp, [rsp]` (I think the fault conditions are identical), but this might have saved transistors in the decoders by adding a uop to the normal way `pop reg` decodes (possibly implicitly requiring a stack-sync uop for a total of 3), instead of treating it as a whole separate instruction?  `pop rsp` is very rarely used so its performance doesn't matter.

Perhaps the 16-bit `pop sp` case was a problem for decoding that byte as 1 pure-load uop?  There is no `[sp]` addressing mode in x86 machine code, and it's *possible* that limitation extends to internal uops for 16-bit AGU.  Other than that, I think the possible fault reasons are the same for `pop` and `mov`.

**`pop r12` (short form) does eventually decode to the normal 1 uop, with no more stack-sync uops than for repeated pop of other registers, as per @Andreas's testing**.  It gets penalized by not being decodeable in the simple decoders, but not by any extra uops that `pop rsp` specifically decodes to.

---

Perhaps GAS, NASM, and other assemblers should get a patch to make it possible to encode `pop r12` with the modrm encoding, although probably not defaulting to that.  Decoder throughput is often not a problem so spending an extra byte of code-size by default would be undesirable.  Especially if there's no effect on other uarches, like AMD or Silvermont-family.

And/or GCC should use R12 as its last choice of call-preserved reg to save/restore?  ([R12 always needs a SIB byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) when used as the base in an addressing mode, too, so that's another reason to avoid it, if compilers aren't going to try to avoid keeping pointers in it.)  And maybe schedule the push/pop of r12 for efficient decoding, with 3 other pops (or other single-uop isns) after it before multi-uop `ret`.

Comment: Actually, the effect does not occur for `push r12`. Also, `push rsp` is decoded to 1 (fused) uop; it is executed as 3 uops, the third of which is likely a stack-synch uop.