# How to get llvm to use the 'OR' instruction for speedup

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, llvm

I have some C code that basically comes down to this:

```
    *p_Bool3 = *p_Bool1 || *p_Bool2;
```

with p_Bool1, p_Bool2 and p_Bool3 being "bool *".

clang++ gives me this assembly for X86 using O2 (O3 makes no difference, I'm just using O2 because thats whats used in the real project):

```
mov eax, dword ptr [esp + 12]
    mov edx, dword ptr [esp + 4]
    mov cl, 1
    cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
    je  LBB1_1
    mov byte ptr [eax], cl
    ret
LBB1_1: 
    mov ecx, dword ptr [esp + 8]
    mov cl, byte ptr [ecx]
    mov byte ptr [eax], cl
    ret
```

The actual program is a little more complex with a bunch ob get and set functions and some overloaded operators but it basically is the same assembly code using O2:

```
001de515  mov         al, 0x01 
001de517  mov         ecx, dword ptr ds:[edi+0x00000628] 
001de51d  cmp         byte ptr ds:[ecx], 0x00000000 
001de520  jne         0x001DE52E 
001de522  mov         eax, dword ptr ds:[edi+0x0000065C] 
001de528  cmp         byte ptr ds:[eax], 0x00000000 
001de52b  setne       al 
001de52e  mov         ecx, dword ptr ds:[edi+0x000005EC] 
001de534  mov         byte ptr ds:[ecx], al
```

Now I have some reference code that runs 75% faster on the same hardware/system that looks like this:

```
0100121e  lea         ebx, dword ptr ds:[esi+0x10280005] 
01001224  mov         al, byte ptr ds:[ebx] 
01001226  lea         ebx, dword ptr ds:[esi+0x10280006] 
0100122c  or          al, byte ptr ds:[ebx] 
0100122e  lea         ebx, dword ptr ds:[esi+0x10280004] 
01001234  mov         byte ptr ds:[ebx], al
```

How can I get clang to just use the 'or' instruction and be faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using an OR operator as in `*p_Bool3 = *p_Bool1 | *p_Bool2`?  The compiler cannot generate this on its own since it is not permitted to dereference `p_Bool2` if `p_Bool1` is true.

If you cannot use a `|` operator here, it should also work to first manually dereference the pointers, telling the compiler that it is permitted to do so:

```
bool tmp1 = *p_Bool1, tmp2 = *p_Bool2;

*p_Bool3 = tmp1 || tmp2;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to set both ```tmp1``` and ```tmp2```? Would ```*p_Bool3 = *p_Bool1 || tmp2``` work or would it have the same risk of side effects as @Jérôme Richard described?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I haven't tried the '|' operator, I actually thought, I should use the '||' operator for bool, so it can be faster. I do like your second suggestion even better since I'm using the "right" operator and still get the fast result. The local variables get completely removed by the optimizer.

Comment: @sj95126 No `tmp1` would certainly work, but anyway using an `|` operator may be the better solution.  Not only does it get rid of the jump, it also possibly avoids extra instructions to normalise the result.

Comment: @sj95126: See [Boolean values as 8 bit in compilers. Are operations on them inefficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243955) - compilers don't always take full advantage of the ABI guarantee that a `bool` is an integer 0 or 1, and will sometimes waste instructions re-booleanizing.

Answer (score 3):

The left/right expressions used with the `||` operator are evaluated **lazily**. Since indirections can cause side effects (eg. page fault, hardware effects), the compiler need to use **conditional to prevent side effects** to occur when they should not.

To avoid this problem, you can use the `|` operator. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/W933oxc6Y) is an example.