# C++ Compiler Efficiency Worse When Creating an Object and Using it on the Same Line

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, compiler-optimization

I am having issues with compile times in my code base. I have found the culprit to be the two lines shown below. With the below code, it takes about **1m 40s** to compile.

```
bool successful=true;
successful&=TreeDebug().run();
successful&=FileDebug().run();
```

```
time g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall -I . -o bin/mainDebug.exe debug/*.hpp debug/*.cpp src/*.hpp src/*.cpp

real    1m41.439s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Separating the creation of the debug objects and the calling of the run method on that object reduces the compile time to **0m 15s**.

```
bool successful=true;
TreeDebug treeDebug;
FileDebug fileDebug;
successful&=treeDebug.run();
successful&=fileDebug.run();
```

```
time g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall -I . -o bin/mainDebug.exe debug/*.hpp debug/*.cpp src/*.hpp src/*.cpp

real    0m14.159s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

What is happening that would increase the time to compile so drastically?

The `Tree` class is a template class, but the last result proves that it is not the template that is causing the issue.

Comment: This code is not equivalent. Did you try to cast the objects in the second sample to rvalues?

Comment: How is it not equivalent? I guess I'm not understanding something fundamental here.

Comment: Looks like this whole thing [is making demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). `&=` is a bitwise operation. A bitwise operation on a `bool` value makes no sense to me, whatsoever. I can't blame a C++ compiler for getting confused over this. I suppose this is not ill-formed, but it's still making the compiler blow a gasket.

Comment: I was thinking that it was shorthand for this: ```successful=(successful && treeDebug.run());``` Am I wrong about that too? Interesting link btw, never heard of that before.

Comment: It is possible that in the first sample the const versions of your `run()` method are called while in the second regular non-const are.

Comment: You don't really see the difference between `&&` and `&`? One is a logical and operator. The other is a bitwise and operator.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I only have non-const methods defined.

Comment: What if you leave just a single class `TreeDebug`? What if you leave the other?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand the difference between ```&``` and ```&&```. Would ```succesfull&&=treeDebug.run();``` be the proper syntax? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577504/is-there-any-difference-between-and-with-bools) seems to say what I'm doing is correct?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Removing the ```TreeDebug``` class had minimal effects on compile time (shaved off a couple seconds out of the original minute fourty).

Comment: Try without putting the `.hpp` files in the compilation command?

Comment: @M.M That did it. Compilation is now down even further to **11s** even with the original code, what does removing the ```.hpp``` files from the command do??

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488406/why-doesnt-c-have-or-for-booleans) proves your point I think. What I'm doing works, but only because both operands are ```bool```'s. But, the link also describes how its not good coding practice, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JackCarmichael gcc builds precompiled headers if you give it .h or .hpp files. Which is a slow procss and generally you would have one (or none) pch for the whole project , not one for every hpp file